# Is it possible to use the meta-files in rtorrent?

Tags: rtorrent

I've used `rtorrent` on some magnetic-links and it created some "meta"-files, which seemed to be named by the hash...

Is there a way to somehow use these meta-files to start `rtorrent` to download the torrents, rather than having to locate the actual magnet?  E.g. rtorrent 637778299.meta or somethin?

Comment: Have you tried just loading the metafile normally? Start rtorrent, press enter, enter the path to the metafile, press enter again?

Comment: That results in 'Could not create download: Object operator [info] could not find element'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment it does not seem to be possible to use those .meta files. There is a pending feature request at [Support .meta->.torrent conversion - Issue #212](https://github.com/rakshasa/rtorrent/issues/212).

Answer (score 1):

Universal method to recreate the magnet link locally on your PC/Mac:

- Assume file name is `EB625F1C3E7131E4D57C14A5B45618B46EDF0D8D.meta`
- Hence the hash is `EB625F1C3E7131E4D57C14A5B45618B46EDF0D8D` and magnet link will be

  ```
  magnet:?xt=urn:btih:EB625F1C3E7131E4D57C14A5B45618B46EDF0D8D&dn=To%20Be%20Resolved&tr=udp://tracker.cyberia.is:6969/announce'
  ```